# Uploading Multiple Files in Android using existing multipart post project

Tags: java, android

I am using a project which upload just one image or video file. http://www.androidhive.info/2014/12/android-uploading-camera-image-video-to-server-with-progress-bar/ downloaded here. I modified the MainActivity

```
File f = new File(Environment
                    .getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                    Config.IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME);

            File[] file = f.listFiles();
            String s= null;
            arrayFiles = new ArrayList<String>();
             if (file.length == 0)
             {
                 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No Files Found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                 finish();
             }

                else {
                    for (int i=0; i<file.length; i++) 
                    {
                        arrayFiles.add(file[i].getName());
                        s=arrayFiles.get(i);
                     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),s , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                     Intent i= new Intent(MainActivity.this, UploadActivity.class);
                     i.putStringArrayListExtra("files", arrayFiles);
                     startActivity(i);
```

This gets me all the files complete path. In uploadActvity

```
 for (int j = 0; j < files.size(); j++) {
                //filePath=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/"+Config.IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME+"/"+files.get(j);
                filePath=files.get(j);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), filePath, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                new UploadFileToServer().execute();
                filePath="";
            }
```

I am using this code for uploading all the files by getting the arrayList from intent and one by one copying path to filePath. But i get EISDIR java io file not found exception although the toast shows correct path sent from main activity. plz help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mistake lies where filePath is nulled. As Async task runs in background, so equating filePath to null gives file not found exception. Some sort of delay must be provided after   new UploadFileToServer().execute();
to let the file upload complete and then load next file. Works!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Add file path to constructor of `UploadFileToServer` like `UploadFileToServer(filePath)`

UploadFileToServer moves your work to background Thread an when this thread would start your filePath would be empty or some other file path. So, bind the file path with your AsyncTask.

Comment: UploadFileToServer(filePath); such constructor is not available. What to do. plz help so that i can get it right and provide more specific answer as i am new to android

Comment: I added a new constructor which accepts filePath but it now uploads just one of the files in the folder.

Comment: That one file is the first file,or last file

Comment: arrayFiles.add(file[i].getName()); you are only setting the name of the file in array, try to set file absolute path instead